# JQuery: Are variables declared inside $(document).ready(); globals? And when can globals be avoided?

Tags: jquery

The concept of globals is starting to solidify. Any variable outside of a function is a global, correct? **If variables are contained within `$(document).ready( function() { *code* } );`, are they considered global?**

I figured out a workaround to put a frequently used array into the function that uses said array, but now I am essentially using my HTML content as my globals, if that makes sense (for example, using text inside a div and passing it into a function). Is this how people typically go about constantly changing/often referenced variables?

If they are not globals, should I still enclose the variables inside functions to develop good practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they're considered **locally** scoped inside the function.

Check this out for JavaScript scoping: https://stackoverflow.com/a/500459/1538708

Scoping variables via functions is good practice, especially if you ever want to run your code through a [minimizer](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/).

Comment: Thanks. Both answers answered my question, I will give you the accepted answer for being first.

Comment: They are "only" 'considered locally scoped inside the function' if the keyword `var` is used when declaring the variable. See Mordhak answer

Answer (score 3):

Variables contained in `$(document).ready` are not global. When you declare a variable in a function, its scope is the function, then the variable won't exist anymore once the function end.

```
var myGlobal = "foo";

$(document).ready(function(){
    var myVar = 42; // myVar will only exist in this scope
    $.myVar = 42; // $.myVar will be accessible anywhere since you have access to '$' object
    // care, this variable will be accessible anywhere
    // if you declare a variable with the same name but omit to add the "var" first, it will work without any error (unless you have "use strict")
    myGlobal = "bar";
});
```

Avoid global variable as much as you can. Don't fall in creating a "god object" containing all you need, your code would just be harder to read and understand.

You can take a look at [`"use strict"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) too.

Comment: Note that `myGlobal`is then available from anywhere, you can check this using `console.log(window.myGlobal)` whereas calling `console.log(window.myVar)` will return `undefined`.